# JSON Parse to Array value not appended properly

Tags: java, android, json

I have an array String[] cruce_no.I am appending Values from JSON response to the array. JSON response is a,b,c .... I need to append value Select to the 0th position of Array 'cruce_no'.
I need result like this {Select,a,b,c...}. But I am getting like this {Select,b,c...}. My code is below:

```
JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject json= null;
    cruce_no = new String[JA.length()];       
    name = new String[JA.length()];

    cruce_no[0] = "Select";

    for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
    {
    json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
    cruce_no[i] = json.getString("
        }
```

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Comment: what's inside your json string?

Comment: a,b,c... I want to append Select into zeroth position of array, but when I did this i miss value 'a'.

Comment: Because it is overwritten..in that case you can also use "select "+JA.getJSONObject(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the size of the array by 1

```
cruce_no = new String[JA.length()+1];


cruce_no[0] = "Select";
```

Inside the `forloop` use this

```
cruce_no[i+1] = json.getString("YOUR_KEY");
```

Answer (score 1):

You getting `{Select,b,c...}` instead  of `{Select,a,b,c...}` because you add Select at 0th position so "a" replaced by "Select"
try like this

```
JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject json= null;
    cruce_no = new String[JA.length()+1];       
    name = new String[JA.length()];

    cruce_no[0] = "Select";

    for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
    {
    json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
    cruce_no[i+1] = json.getString("
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make array size  `new String[JA.length()+1]` as you are going to add an extra element `select` in it. And then place select at 0th positon followed by rest of the elements. So 0th position should not be overwritten.